# Can't solve a issue with for loop

Tags: python

I can't solve how to write this loop properly, it's 90% done but I can't solve this:

```
string.replace(archive_header, "titlefixed", titlefixed)
```

which must be included in this for loop

```
for arfosers in archive_header, forum_header, search_header, rss_header:
    arfosers.write(rss_header + string.replace(footer_p, "<!-- recent posts -->", postgroup))
    arfosers.close()
```

(help me to gete rid of "rss header arfosers.write line)

These are the lines that I want to do in a 'for' loop:

```
archive_header = string.replace(archive_header, "titlefixed", titlefixed)
archive_file.write(archive_header + archive_body + string.replace(footer_p, "<!-- recent posts -->", postgroup))
archive_file.close()

forum_header = string.replace(forum_header, "titlefixed", titlefixed)
forum_file.write(forum_header + string.replace(footer_p, "<!-- recent posts -->",     postgroup))
forum_file.close()

search_header = string.replace(search_header, "titlefixed", titlefixed)
search_file.write(search_header + string.replace(footer_p, "<!-- recent posts -->", postgroup))
search_file.close()

rss_header = string.replace(rss_header, "titlefixed", titlefixed)
rss_file.write(rss_header + string.replace(footer_p, "<!-- recent posts -->", postgroup))
rss_file.close()
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to shorten the whole code by putting these 13 lines in a for loop that will make the code readable also with lesser lines.

Comment: @SpringField: The first batch is different (there are 3 terms in the argument to write instead of two). There is enough different variables that I don't think it will actually be more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
data = (
    (archive_file, archive_header, archive_body),
    (forum_file, forum_header, forum_body),
    (search_file, search_header, search_body),
    (rss_file, rss_header, rss_body)
)

for file, header, body in data:
    header = string.replace(header, "titlefixed", titlefixed)
    file.write(header + body + string.replace(footer_p, "<!-- recent posts -->", postgroup))
    file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you freakish and everyone else that made suggestions. This is the exact thing that I needed freakish :)

Comment: I was writing a similiar answer. One correction though, the  question doesn't have forum_body , search_body and rss_body. :)

Comment: @iamkhush There is `archive_body` in the second snippet (so I thought that it might matter, it can be replaced with empty strings in other cases). But what is really important is the idea. :)

Answer (score 2):

for each structure elements are read only as I know. try for loop with indexing.

Answer (score 1):

```
lStuff = [
        (archive_header,archive_file), 
        (forum_header,forum_file), 
        (search_header,search_file), 
        (rss_header,rss_file)
        ]
for header,file in lStuff:
    header = string.replace(header, "titlefixed", titlefixed)
    file.write(header + string.replace(footer_p, "<!-- recent posts -->",postgroup))
    file.close
```